# Is it safe to upgrade a current mysql CentOS 6.0 server to CentOS 6.5?

Tags: php5, drbd, upgrade, centos6.5

This server has specific configuration of php, it is also acting as a node in a DRBD cluster which holds a critical MYSQL database.
I wanted to know if [this](http://geek-kb.com/?p=1009&preview=true) procedure is safe and if there are any other actions I should take other than backing up configuration files before the upgrade? Thanks

There used to be a Fusion IO card acting as storage on the primary node f the cluster, but we had problems with it and in the end I decided to disassemble the card and replace it with 6x 15k SAS disks.
After that I re-installed the machine on the new disks and just because they're both nodes of the same cluster I figured that it would be wise to upgrade the slave node as well as the CentOS version there is 6.0
Please correct me if I'm wrong or if you do not recommend to upgrade it.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to upgrade?

Comment: If the system is as critical as you make out, I wouldn't be updating it based on some $RANDOM person's answer on an internet Q&A site. I'd be making a copy of it and testing things in a lab no matter what people here say.

Comment: It's not just about mysql. For example a bug in the rhel6.4 kernel prevented me from upgrading my rhel6.0 server. (involving a mount problem of a ramdisk). This would have been a show stopper if it entered production. So better test it in every possible way before doing this upgrade, and don't focus only on mysql, but also on mounts, authentication, etc...

Comment: Thanks man, my boss and myself decided to format the server and do a clean installation. Thanks for your answers.